# IllegalArgumentException while Export to Excel Using Apache POI Api

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
  How to resolve The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32,767 characters
```

When i try to run the export to excel using Apache POI , I am getting the following error

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32,767 characters 
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellValue(HSSFCell.java:548) 
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellValue(HSSFCell.java:522)

How can i resolve this without limiting the Content to allow more than 32,767 characters

I humbly request everyone's Valuable suggestions. Please help

Comment: 32767 characters is a hard limit from the excel document itself. I think you need to separate your original text into separate columns (or rows) so that you can still display them in your spreadsheet. See [Javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html#EXCEL2007) for info on excel spreadsheet limits